# How do I call jQuery $.widget.bridge() base $.Widget.destroy() method?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, widget

I am using jQuery ;$.widget.bridge(); and want to destroy widget instances and I can't work out how to call the `$.widegt.destroy()` method.

```
// Bridge to our FileSelect plugin.
$.widget.bridge( "fileSelect", FileSelect );

// Wire up 'File' select.
$('#fileSelect').fileSelect({
        onchange: jQuery.proxy( viewModel.handleFiles, viewModel ); 
});

....
// Now destroy the fileSelect widget?
```

Ref:
http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/using-jquery-ui-widget-factory-bridge/
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/1.8.5/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js#L81

**Update** Changed Title to better reflect intent.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: This answer is **incorrect**, as far as we (the OP and I can tell). I'll remove it after a time, but I'm leaving it for now so that others don't post the same thing. See the comments for details.

---

The usual way with jQuery UI widgets would be:

```
$('#fileSelect').fileSelect('destroy');
```

Note that the "method" name is in quotes, and passed as an argument to the plugin function.

**Update**: And this is mentioned on that [first link you listed](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/using-jquery-ui-widget-factory-bridge/):

> `$.widget.bridge` works inside the factory by taking your base "foo" object and giving it a public API, so that you can create instances by writing `$('.foo').bar()`, **and call methods by writing `$('.foo').bar('baz')`.**

*(My emphasis.)* ...and so presumably applies to widgets created via that bridge as well.

Comment: Yes this calls my widgets destroy() method, but that's not what I want. I want to call $.Widget.destroy() (see linked source) to remove the widget from the DOM - unbind(), removeData() etc.

Comment: @nevf: Are you sure the above doesn't do that? It certainly looks like it should. `$.widget.bridge` is registering itself as the jQuery UI widget and then brokering calls to your underlying object. `$.widget.bridge` defines the standard "destroy" method, and so the above should call it. I'd do it and walk the code, but I expect you'll find yourself inside `$.Widget.prototype.destroy`.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder. I'd had a quick look and convinced myself that wasn't the case, for several reasons. Hence this post. However you may be right. I'm using a minified version of jQuery-UI so it's very difficult to step though and see what's happening. I'll need to get an unminified version and revisit it. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder. Ok I've tried an unminified copy of jquery.ui.widget.js and can't see $Widget.destroy() being called, just my widgets destroy() method.

Comment: @nevf: Very strange. In a normal jQuery UI widget you'd be calling `destroy` yourself from your own destroy method, like this: `$.Widget.prototype.destroy.apply(this, arguments);` Does that work? I haven't used `$.widget.bridge` and put together a test case but I think I don't have the test case right. In any case, when I add that call (which again is how you would normally do it), it fails, but perhaps that's my test case. Be interested to know what happens at your end.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder. I added $.Widget.prototype.destroy.apply(this, arguments); in my widgets destroy method and the call succeeds however I then get: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLButtonElement> has no method 'unbind'. Note that I currently have both the minified and unminified versions of jquery.ui.widget.js which could be problematic.

Comment: @nevf: Yeah, that's the result I got too. Well, this answer is clearly not the right one. I'm not at all sure you haven't found a problem with `$.widget.bridge`. I can't really say I'm seeing how it offers you much of anything over just doing a widget the normal way...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried .remove()?

http://api.jquery.com/remove

Comment: I don't want to remove the html element. I want to destroy the widget associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider adding bridge to a class and then applying the class to widget using [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and then you can remove the class using [removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

```
$.widget.addClass('someclass');
$('someclass').bridge( "fileSelect", FileSelect );
```

Then to remove ,

```
$.widget.removeClass('someclass');
```